# Reversing last n digits of an Integer in C

Tags: c

I need to write a program that takes 2 digits(X and n) and then prints X with last n digits of X reversed.

For example

Input: 12345 3

Output: 12543

Input: 523 2

Output: 532

I already wrote a control mechanism for checking n is greater or equal than the number of digits of X
For example if inputs are 6343 and 7, program prints that inputs should be changed and takes input again.

My main problem is I couldn't find an algorithm for reversing last n digits. I can reverse any int with this code

```
  int X, r = 0;

  printf("Enter a number to reverse\n");
  scanf("%d", &n);

  while (X != 0)
  {
    r = r * 10;
    r = r + n%10;
    X = X/10;
  }

  printf("Reverse of the number = %d", r);
```

But I couldn't figure how two reverse just last digits. Can you give me any idea for that?

Comment: Probably easiest to convert input value to a char array, modify that, then convert back (if needed).

Comment: Also you 'n' variable is undeclared. Unless this is only part of your code?

Comment: Or, since your input is a character string, don't bother converting it to int in the first place. (eg, don't use `scanf("%d",...`

Comment: Watch out for floating point problems with solutions that use `pow(10,...)` and its _almost_ correct answers.  Best to use integer math for integer type problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
It is an easy one.
1. let say the number you want to reverse is curr_number;
2. Now, the places you want to reverse is x; 
 (remember to verify that x must be less than the number of digit of curr_number);
3. now, just take a temp integer and store curr_number / pow(10,x) ('/' = divide and pow(10,x) is 10 to the power x)
4. now, take a second number temp2, which will store curr_number-(temp * pow(10,x) )
5. reverse this temp2 (using your function)
6. now, answer = (temp * pow(10,x) ) + (temp2) //(note temp2 is reversed)
```

example with steps:

1. curr_number = 1234567
2. places you want to reverse is 3
3. temp = 1234567 / (10^3) i.e (1234567/1000) = 1234 (because it is int type)
4. temp2 = 1234567 - (1234*10^3) i.e 1234567 - 1234000 = 567
5. reverse(567) = 765
6. answer = (1234 * 10^3) + 765 = 1234765

Answer (score 2):

> I couldn't figure how to reverse just last digits

Separate the number using `pow(10,n)` - see later code.

```
unsigned reverse_last_digits(unsigned x, unsigned n) {
  unsigned pow10 = powu(10, n);
  unsigned lower = x%pow10;
  unsigned upper = x - lower;
  return upper + reverseu(lower, n);
}
```

Create a loop that extracts the least-significant-digit (`%10)` and builds up another integer by applying that digit. (`y = y*10 + new_digit`)

```
unsigned reverseu(unsigned x, unsigned n) {
  unsigned y = 0;
  while (n-- > 0) {
    y = y*10 + x%10;
    x /= 10;
  }
  return y;
}
```

For integer type problems, consider integer helper functions and avoid floating point functions like `pow()` as they may provide only an approximate results.  Easy enough to code an integer `pow()`.

```
unsigned powu(unsigned x, unsigned expo) {
  unsigned y = 1;
  while (expo > 0) {
    if (expo & 1) {
      y = x * y;
    }
    expo >>= 1;
    x *= x;
  }
  return y;
}
```

Test

```
int main() {
  printf("%u\n", reverse_last_digits(12345, 3));
  printf("%u\n", reverse_last_digits(523, 2));
  printf("%u\n", reverse_last_digits(42001, 3));
  printf("%u\n", reverse_last_digits(1, 2));
}
```

Output

```
12543
532
42100
10
```

Code uses `unsigned` rather than `int` to avoid *undefined behavior* (UB) on `int` overflow.

Comment: `reverse_last_digits(42001, 3)` returns the wrong value 42001 instead of 42100 because `reverseu(1)` returns 1.

Answer (score 1):

- Create two variables

  - `lastn` which stores the last n digits (345)
  - `r` which stores the reversed last n digits (543)
- Subtract `lastn` from the original number (12345 - 345 = 12000)
- Add `r` to the above number (12000 + 543 = 12543)

```
int c = 0; // count number of digits
int original = x;
int lastn = 0;
while (x != 0 && c < n) {
    r = r * 10;
    r = r + x % 10;
    lastn += (x % 10) * pow(10, c);
    x = x / 10;
    c++;
}
printf("reversed: %d\n", original - lastn + r);
```

Comment: Using `pow` is frowned upon for this assignment. Also why do you stop at `x == 0`? `garble(1, 2)` should return `10`.

Answer (score 1):

In case you don't have problems using `char`, you can do this

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define SIZE 10

int main() {

    char n[SIZE]; // the Number;
    int x; // number of last digits of n to reverse
    int len; // number of digits of n

    scanf("%s%d", n, &x);

    len = strlen(n);

    for(int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    
        i < len - x ? printf("%c", n[i]) : printf("%c", n[2*len -1 - i - x]);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

If you want you can make the program more readable by splitting the `for` in two

```
for(int i = 0; i < len - x; i++) {
    printf("%c", n[i]);
}
for(int i = len-1; i >= len - x; i--) {
    printf("%c", n[i]);
}
```

Note: the program won't work if n > x (i.e. if you want to swap more digits than you got)